# How to JSON.stringify an nested array of objects

Tags: arrays, react-native, fetch-api, stringify, react-state-management

This is my data,

```
 data =  {
        "SeatingArrangement": [{
           "data": [{"id": 1, "rowName": "a", "seatNo": 0},{ "id": 2,"rowName": "a","seatNo": "a1"}],
           "rowName": "a",
        }],
        "TheatreName": "abc natyadalan",
     }
```

I want to stringify this data and send to API, but in my Fetch.js while stringify this data I'm getting error as,

**Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'SeatingArrangement', line 1, position 54.**

Comment: you're not opening the string for the key: `id"`

Comment: what are you using to stringify your Object? using `JSON.stringify(data)` seems to work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue.

First I did JSON.stringify on **SeatingArrangement** object and then the whole data object.

Answer (score 0):

Mistakes:

- `data =` at the start of the JSON. You cannot have an = .
- `"rowName": "a",` comma after "a".
- "TheatreName": "abc natyadalan", Again a comma at the end

Fix these and you get a valid JSON.
I wish you had gone through [JSONLint](https://jsoncompare.com/#!/simple/). You could have seen whether you are having a valid JSON or not.

Comment: data is my variable which I'm passing to my Fetch API and there is no problem with it.

Comment: Actually the json is created dynamically. I can't do anything with trailing comma's. Trying to find solution to remove it. Thanks for your response. @Sparker0i

Comment: When you Stringify that data, you will get error because that is not a valid JSON data... It is not in JSON format at all. JSONs just cannot have =

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem with JSON.stringify. The problem is that you forgot an `"`before `"id"`.